# Predicate Logic Family Members

Tags: predicate-logic

I am having a bit of trouble with predicate logic involving family members.

This is a question from an assignment I am doing.

Let the domain be a group of three dogs, Tiger, Ashes and Smokey. Consider the following premises:

• ∀x∀y(Puppy(x) ∧ ¬Puppy(y) → Parent(y, x))

• ∀x∀y(Parent(x, y) → ¬Puppy(x))

• ∀x∀y(Parent(x, y) → Puppy(y))

• Parent(Smokey, Ashes)

• ¬Puppy(Tiger)

Use predicate logic natural deduction to figure out the relationship between Tiger and Ashes.
Hint: if you have two (or more) universal quantifiers in a row, you can treat them as one
quantifier for a pair of elements, and instantiate them together in universal modus ponens.
Also, use the rule that from A and B you can derive A ∧ B in one step.

It seems that Tiger is the parent of Ashes. I don't know how to prove that though (outside of just looking at it and making a deduction)

Comment: It is not a tautology.  It is satisfyable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

$\fitch{
1. \forall x \forall y \ ( (Puppy(x) \land \neg Puppy(y))\rightarrow Parent(y,x))\\
2. \forall x \forall y \ (Parent(x,y) \rightarrow \neg Puppy(x))\\
3. \forall x \forall y \ (Parent(x,y) \rightarrow Puppy(y))\\
4. Parent(smokey, ashes)\\
5. \neg Puppy(tiger)}{
6. Parent(smokey, ashes)\rightarrow Puppy(ashes) \quad \forall \ Elim \ 3\\
7. Puppy(ashes) \quad \rightarrow \ Elim \ 4,6\\ 
8. Puppy(ashes) \land \neg Puppy(tiger) \quad \land \ Intro \ 5,7\\
9. (Puppy(ashes) \land \neg Puppy(tiger)) \rightarrow Parent(tiger,ashes) \quad \forall \ Elim \ 1\\
10. Parent(tiger,ashes) \quad \rightarrow \ Elim \ 8,9
}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you have any resources that explain this process ,so that I can understand it, please let me know

Comment: @asdfjkdsg  There are many online resources ... but you often find small differences in how the rules are exactly fleshed out.  Anyway, here's a [decent set of slides on predicate logic proofs](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/dmmr/slides/13-14/Ch1c.pdf) (I just googled 'Predicate Logic Proofs')

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that Tiger is the parent of Ashes. I don't know how to prove that though (outside of just looking at it and making a deduction)

That is basically what you have to do.  Just state what parts you are looking at when using logical deduction, and which rule use use of the two rules of inference you are allowed.

- Parent(Smokey, Ashes) and ∀x∀y(Parent(x, y) → Puppy(y)) entails that Puppy(Ashes), via universal modus ponens.
- Puppy(Ashes), and ¬Puppy(Tiger) entails *what conclusion* via *which rule*.
- *This conclusion*, and *which premise* entails Parent(Tiger, Ashes) via *which rule*.

Also

- Parent(Smokey, Ashes) and ∀x∀y(Parent(x, y) → ¬Puppy(x)) entails that ¬Puppy(Smokey), via universal modus ponens.

---

Note: if you can also use universal modus tolens you can also similarly make quite a few more conclusions.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped. I appreciate it. Unfortunately I am unable to give you + due to my noob rating.